# Base locus under a pull-back

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fiber-bundles

Let $\pi: Y \to X$ be a surjective morphism of smooth projective varieties.

**Question**: Suppose the linear system $|D|$ of a divisor $D$ on $X$ is base-point free. Is the linear system $|\pi^*D|$  also base-point free?

Here $\pi^*$ is the pull-back. I have seen there are statements about pulling back ample or very ample line bundles, but these do not seem quite the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assumption that $|D|$ is base-point free means that there is a surjective morphism
$$
V \otimes \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X(D).
$$
The pullback functor is right-exact, hence the pullback of the above morphism
$$
V \otimes \mathcal{O}_Y \to \pi^*\mathcal{O}_X(D) = \mathcal{O}_Y(\pi^*D)
$$
is surjective, which means that $\pi^*D$ is base-point free.

Comment: This is a perfect answer, thank you. Just to check, $V = H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(D))$?

Comment: You can take this $V$ or any other space which is big enough. In this way the argument works for non-projective varieties and for incomplete linear systems.